# the processResult in select2 do not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I use select2 loading remote data I send an ajax request and get the response correctly but the processResult don't run and nothing will be show

the javascript code :

```
var formatProduct= 
function(product) {
    console.log("formatProduct");
    if (product.loading) return product.text;
    var markup =  '<div class="product-to-compare" data=' + product.id + '>' + product.name + '</div>' ;
    return markup;
  }
var formatProductSelection = 
function (product) {
console.log("formatProductSelection");
return product.name || product.text;
}
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for product",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: '/product/ajax_product_list/',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 300,
        data: function (params) {
            var id = $('#product-no-1').attr('data') ;
            return {
                key: params,
                id: id
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: data.items
        };     
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatProduct, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatProductSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

and the JSON that my controller return as a response :

```
{
"items": [
  {"id": "55dd980c8242b630cfaf4788", "name": "sallll"},
  {"id": "55d58d7a8242b62c6b88504e", "name" : "inja"}, 
  {"id": "55d58d558242b62c6b88504d", "name": "salam"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rename your JSON to return `text` instead of `name`.

Note that if you're using an older version of `select2` (<4) you should use `results` instead of `processResults`.

Comment: I just rename the `name` to `text` in JSON file but nothing happen ! 
and even when I put a `console.log("something")` in `ProcessResults` function nothing printed in browser console ! @uri2x

Comment: Is it possible that you're getting cached data? Try removing `cache:true`.

Comment: I do it and still I can't get the response and now I found another problem ! 
my browser console show me an error that I can't understand it ! 
maybe it's cause of problem 
the error : 
`TypeError: c.results is not a function
 

...taType,data:d,success:function(a){var b=c.results(a,i.page);i.callback(b)}}),e`

Comment: yeah I just change `processResult` to `results` and now I receive the data in my drop down form !

Comment: Congrats! (but you're probably using an old version of `select2`)

Comment: but when I use `results` function the `delay` property not working and browser send AJAX with every key down !

Comment: is there a way to use `delay` property in this old version of select2 ?

Comment: yeah man you were right ! the select2 that used in project was old I just update it and now everything is working good ! 
but if I don't edit my JSON file I have that problem even in new version of select2 !  
thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
processResults: function (data) {
  //There is my solution.Just directly manipulate the data
  $.each(data.items, function(i, d) {
    data.items[i]['text'] = d.name;
  });
  return {
      results: data.items
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight the parts that solve the question? A reader should be able to learn quickly from your answer

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was refreshing the page and looking for the http request sent to fetch search data. So make sure you do a search to `processResult` get called.

Comment: Sorry for posting a stupid answer. Hope this helps someone anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON data, you rename **name** to **text**. Because select2 data only accepts column names **id** and **text**.